# How to update sqlite database using given username not by id . .I tried with below code but its not working

Tags: android, sqlite

//In database File

```
public void uupdate(String u1, String l1, String m1, String a1,String gotUname) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues updating = new ContentValues();
    updating.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, u1);
    updating.put(KEY_LASTNAME, l1);
    updating.put(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, m1);
    updating.put(KEY_ADDRESS, a1);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updating,KEY_FIRSTNAME +"=" +gotUname+"" , null);

}
```

//User main file

```
package com.example.cabs4u;
import com.example.cabs4u.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class User_main extends Activity{
    EditText uname,lname,mnum,addre;
    Button update;
    String gotUname;
    Main_database get = new Main_database(User_main.this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_user);

        Bundle gotString = getIntent().getExtras();

        gotUname=gotString.getString("usrname");
        TextView grt;
        grt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);
        grt.setText("Hello "+ gotUname);
        uname =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname1);
        lname =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname1);
        mnum =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mbnumber1);
        addre =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.addr1);

        update =(Button)findViewById(R.id.udate);
        get.open();
        String gusername = get.getuname(gotUname);
        String mnmbr = get.mnum(gotUname);
        String maddr= get.madd(gotUname);
        uname.setText(gotUname);
        lname.setText(gusername);
        mnum.setText(mnmbr);
        addre.setText(maddr);
        get.close();
        TabHost th;
        th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab11);
        specs.setIndicator("        Find Your Cab                 ");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab22);
        specs.setIndicator("            Update Profile              ");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab33);
        specs.setIndicator("            Other                    ");
        th.addTab(specs);
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String u1 = uname.getText().toString();
                String l1 = lname.getText().toString();
                String m1 = mnum.getText().toString();
                String a1 = addre.getText().toString();
                if(!(u1.isEmpty() && l1.isEmpty() && m1.isEmpty() && a1.isEmpty()))
                {
                get.open();
                get.uupdate(u1,l1,m1,a1,gotUname);
                Dialog d = new Dialog(User_main.this);
                d.setTitle(gotUname + "You updated your profile");
                d.show();
                get.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals need to be `'quoted'`, or even better, parametrized like this:

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updating,KEY_FIRSTNAME +"=?", new String[] { gotUname });
```